# Update already existing values while adding new ones

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm inserting some values into my database.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `name`, `nickname`, `prefix`, `suffix`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss",$row['member_id'], $row['name'], $row['nickname'], $row['prefix'], $row['suffix']);
$stmt->execute();
```

This does what I want: if a new user has joined this will add them to members. However, if an already existing member has changed their nickname this info doesn't get updated. I would like to 1) add new members like it currently does but also 2) update the nicknames for already existing members if there are any changes.

I tried adding the following code after the one above (first add members and then update) but it doesn't seem to work as I wanted.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE members SET nickname = '?' WHERE id = '?'");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$row['nickname'], $row['id']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: just get rid of quotes as `.... nickname = ? WHERE id = ?`

Comment: Hmm. Looks like that did the trick and now I wonder why did I have those there... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO`
Your prepare() would have

```
REPLACE INTO `members` (`id`, `name`, `nickname`, `prefix`, `suffix`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

REPLACE updates the new data if the primary key value already exists.
More details here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue with this is REPLACE INTO deletes the row before inserting. I have some other values in the database and I would like to only replace one column which is changing, not the entire row. Would `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` do the job?

Comment: Yes. In that case you can use `INSERT.. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.